# move block and figures arbitrarily

Tags: positioning

I would like to put a figure in the right part of a slide and text in the left part, in order to explain the figure.

Then i would like to put another block at the bottom of the slide.

I'm using Beamer.

How can I move blocks and figures in a single slide?

Comment: Wrap each side in a `minipage`. ie, `\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth} <content on left> \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth} <picture on right> \end{minipage}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `columns` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe} %For dummy image


\author{The author}
\title{The title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}{Frame subtitle}

\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
    The Explanation
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{block}{title}
content
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]